# Find with regex parametr from variable

Tags: regex, bash, find

I want to create script which use find like this:

```
find . -regex $1 | while read prom; do
    echo $prom
done
```

I want to get regex from option but I can´t get this working. I tried use some regex (f. e. ".*(txt)§" ) direct instead of $1 but it didn´t help. What I forget about using find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason you have brackets there? Try `.*txt$` as your regex (not that funny "section symbol" sign in your question).

If you did want the brackets (as capturing brackets?) you have to do `.*\(txt\)$`, because the default regex type for `find` is Emacs-style, in which `()` are *literal* and have to be escaped to be interpreted in their regex sense.

You can also do `find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*(txt)$'`, noting the `-regextype posix-extended` which changes the regex to extended POSIX regex, where `()` *are* special characters (`find -regextype asdf` will usually give you an error message listing all the options you can feed in for `regextype`).

Also, in your bash script, you should surround the `$1` in quotes :

```
find . -regex "$1"
```

(Unless `$1` is already fed in with quotes around it, in which case disregard the suggestion).

Comment: My example should looks like `.*\(txt\)$` but I don´t know in text I must use \\ (and that symbol there was problem with coping). Your answer help me with quotes. Thanks

Comment: "(Unless $1 is already fed in with quotes around it, in which case disregard the suggestion)" -- no, it doesn't matter how it was quoted when passed in to the script/function: when you "dereference" the variable use quotes.